# PHP Remove All Characters After Final - Character

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to list some titles on my site, but these titles also contain information I want to hide, such as:

> Need For Speed - Update 1.02
>
> One Piece: Pirate Warriors 3 - 0
>
> Toukiden: Kiwami - Demo - 0

As you can see, these titles contain numbers `- {num}` at the end, or `Update {num}`.

I've tried to remove these using this:

```
$displayname = substr($item['displayname'], 0, strpos($item['displayname'], ' - '));
```

This works for some titles, but titles without containing these characters will be removed like `LIMBO`.

I'm trying to find a perfect solution for this. I've thought about using regex to find either  `- Update {random}` and  `- {random}` at the end of the title to replace it with nothing, but I'm unsure how to execute this.

I hope someone can help me further!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do something like this:

```
function stripEnd($title){
  return preg_replace('/\-\s*(Update\s*)?[0-9.]+$/', '', $title);
}
$need = stripEnd('Need For Speed - Update 1.02');
$piece = stripEnd('One Piece: Pirate Warriors 3 - 0');
$kiwami = stripEnd('Toukiden: Kiwami - Demo - 0');
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation?

Comment: This appears to work the best for me, I've now perfected my page using your solution.

Answer (score 1):

if you have to delete the last part of the string after the last '-', you can use this:

`$newTitle = substr($title, 0, strripos($title, '-') -1 );`

check the docu:

[substr](http://php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php) and [strripos](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strripos.php)

Hope that help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 $temp = explode("-",$item['displayname']);
 $displayname = $temp[0];
```

This will strip any info after any '-' and any without a '-' will still work.

Comment: This indeed works, however, it also strips `- demo` from some titles. I rather keep that to the title.

Comment: At that point you are going to have some fun times with Regex.   Its going to get complicated